# Command ‘last’ - problems

Tags: last

I have this problem using the command ‘last’. My task is to find names of people, that have been logged in at night hours (22:00 - 5:00). So I’ve tried to save the first number (22) to a variable and wanted to compare, but it doesn’t work at all.

This is how it looks like.

```
@ a =  `last | cut -c 55-56 `
```

And I’ve also tried this:

```
@ a =  `last | tr -s “ “ “ “ | cut -d “ “ -f7 | cut -d “:” -f1 `
```

But none of this worked it always says “Ambiguous” and I really don’t know what I’m doing wrong. I’m new in this and I would be very thankful if somebody helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Is this in a shell script or a Perl script or something else?

Comment: If the environment is running systemd, you may be better served using journalctl with --since --until and -t systemd-logind

Comment: careful with those quotes -- they appear to be "smart" quotes here; hopefully your actual command uses `"normal"` quotes?